# Ubuntu 14.04.5 System Settings Won't Launch

Tags: 14.04, system-settings

I recently installed Ubuntu 14.04.5 and now I'm having issues launching System Settings. I was able to launch it initially, but the only thing that's changed is that I've installed CUDA, and now it isn't launching. My screen size is oddly large (see below), which is why I'm trying to change it through System Settings. If there's another way of doing it (I'm using a Qnix monitor + Titan X Pascal graphics card), please let me know!

[Oddly large display.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYwcX.png)

Here's what I've tried:

- uninstalling and reinstalling System Settings (`sudo apt-get remove unity-control-center`, `sudo apt-get install unity-control-center`)
- typing `unity-control-center` and `gnome-control-center`, which results in this output for unity: `(unity-control-center:6209): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_strsplit: assertion 'string != NULL' failed
  Segmentation fault (core dumped)`, and this for gnome: `(unity-control-center:6296): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_strsplit: assertion 'string != NULL' failed
  Segmentation fault (core dumped)`
- `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`: no change